# can't get monitor mode for my galaxy alpha's wifi in stock rom

Tags: wi-fi, linux

so i am trying to do the monitor mode for my phone's wifi
which is samsung galaxy alpha sm-g850f running stock 5.0.2,
and i used the bcmon app and it says no firmware detected .

also i installed kali linux through linux deploy app,
and whenever i try to do the monitor mode for my wlan0 using airmon-ng command,
it just says an error `there is no such device (-19)`

and i have no idea where to start to know the problem,

i thought maybe i the chipset if the wifi doesn't support that thing,
so if i bought a usb external wifi card and connect it via otg , would it do the job as wlan1? or is there a way to fix the wlan0?

Answer (score -1):

You might try this, i want to try that too: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2338179

Comment: You should summarize the approach you are linking. Otherwise, if the link disappears your answer becomes useless.